# SQLite and Python, getting just text value from table

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I´m trying to get a clean output value from a sqlite table but not luck so far. The output value has , ' and () on it.

```
>>> import sqlite3

>>> db = sqlite3.connect('C:\\Users\\userRock\\Desktop\\gen_profile.sqlite')
>>> cur = db.cursor()

>>> cur.execute (''' CREATE TABLE user (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name TEXT) ''')
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x002E0EE0>
>>> db.commit()

>>> cur.execute (''' INSERT INTO user(name) VALUES ('John'),('James') ''')
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x002E0EE0>
>>> db.commit()

>>> cur.execute (''' SELECT name FROM user ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1 ''')
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x002E0EE0>

>>> text = cur.fetchone()
>>> print (text)
('James',)
>>>
```

The output is ('James,) but I'd like to get James, just the name without symbols. How could I do that?

Thank you very much

Comment: `text = cur.fetchone()[0]`

Comment: or `print(text[0])` usually you get a `tuple` when you do queries like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With that code, `text` is tuple, which can contain multiple values. You just want one. You can retrieve the first (in this case the only) item from it like this: `print (text[0])`. Or, you can just assign the first value when you get it: `text = cur.fetchone()[0]`